# How do I display a matplotlib plot in the console in Foundry Code Workbook?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-code-workbooks

What is the best way of displaying a matplotlib plot in the console within Foundry Code Workbook?

Answer (score 1):

To display a `matplotlib` plot in the console in code workbook, you need to run the command to create the plot and show the plot in the same command. You can attempt this using the example below:

```
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
... plt.scatter([1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4])
... plt.show()
```